# Linux sed command to return truncated output

Tags: linux, sed

I have an example command `aws describe-something command` which returns the following output.

```
{
    "Image": [
        {
            "Name": "tyy1", 
            "VpcConfig": {
                "SubnetIds": [
                    "subnet-800jhoic9"
                ], 
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    "sg-jj-popttf5"
                ]
            }, 
            "EnableDefaultInternetAccess": false, 
            "ImageBuilderErrors": [], 
            "Platform": "WINDOWS", 
            "State": "SNAPSHOTTING", 
            "InstanceType": "stream.standard.medium"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using this command `aws describe-something | grep -i State | sed -n -e 's/^.*\"State\": //p'` to return SNAPSHOTTING however I am getting "SNAPSHOTTING". How do I remove the comma and double quote?

Comment: Use sed 's/\"//g'

Comment: You might need to provide the full command

Comment: aws describe-something | grep -i State | sed -n -e 's/\"//g'

Comment: nah...it doesnt return anything..

Comment: strange it works for me ok try 
aws describe-something | grep -i State | sed 's/\"//g